# Problemas con c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dev-c++, visual-c++

Hola estoy trabajando en un proyecto personal con c++ al momento de incluir estas librerías

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <locale.h>
```

Marca este error: no se puede abrir el archivo origen (código de erro)

Asi mismo en el identificador System, getch(), cout y cin me marca este error: El identificador no esta definido.

Igualmente estoy realizando una raiz cuadrado esta es la linea de codigo: radio = sqrt((pow(valorH, 2)) + (pow(valorK, 2)) - valorF); y me dice que mas de una linea de funcion sobrecargada coincide con la lista de argumentos.

El proyecto originalemente se hizo en C y corre bien pero al pasar a c++ me esta dando estos problemas.Alguien sabra como puedo solucionarlos.

estoy ejecutando en un proyecto de visual-studio.

Comment: Así a bote pronto, `cout` necesita de `iostream`, y usarlo en el namespace `std`. Sobre el resto de cabeceras, `conio` no sirve para nada, y las otras, seguramente alguna no las necesites, pero en todo caso las cabeceras de C++ empiezan con c y no llevan el .h. Por ejemplo, "math.h" sería "cmath", "stdlib.h"sería "cstdlib", etc

Comment: probare estas soluciones y traigo el resultado muchas gracias.

Comment: `string.h` funciona con `char *`. Si quieres trabajar de mejor manera con cadenas de texto, usa `string`.

Comment: He logrado solucionar lo de las librerias, aun tengo problemas con la raiz cuadrada la linea de codigo es: radio = sqrt((pow(valorH, 2)) + (pow(valorK, 2)) - valorF); la variable radio la tengo declarada como double, sin embargo me tira este error: más de una instancia de función sobrecargada coincide con la lista de argumentos, alguna idea para solucionarlo?

Comment: de igual manera, hay dos getch y un system que me dan el error: El identificador "" no esta definidio esto a que se debe o de que manera se puede solucionar las lineas de codigo donde me da este error son:
 system("COLOR 0A");//Color de fondo

cout << "\nPresione una tecla para continuar\n";
            getch(); (Aqui el getch es el que manda el error)